# Auto Layout for dynamic/draggable UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, constraints, autolayout

I am trying to have a draggable UIView within my ViewController, eventually this UIView will become a clickable button but for now, I am stuck with updating the constraints of this view when it is dragged on the screen. The code is below.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.anotherView = [[UIView alloc]init];
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dragging:)];
    [self.anotherView addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];
    [self.anotherView setBackgroundColor: [UIColor blueColor]];
    self.anotherView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    [self.view addSubview: self.anotherView];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.anotherView];

    NSDictionary *views = @{@"subview" : self.anotherView, @"superview" : self.view};

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.anotherView
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationLessThanOrEqual
                                                             toItem:self.view
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                         multiplier:1.0
                                                           constant:0]];

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.anotherView
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationLessThanOrEqual
                                                             toItem:self.view
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                         multiplier:1.0
                                                           constant:0]];


    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.anotherView
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:Nil
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                         multiplier:1.0
                                                           constant:20]];

    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                               constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[subview(40)]"
                               options:0
                               metrics:nil
                               views:views]];
        // add horizontal constraints

    /*[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[subview(==20)]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

     // set the height of the offscreen subview to be the same as its superview

     [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[subview(==40)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

     // set the location of the subview to be just off screen below the current view

     NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.anotherView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationLessThanOrEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:1.0 constant:self.view.bounds.size.height];
     [self.view addConstraint:constraint];*/
        //[self.anotherView pinEdges:JRTViewPinLeftEdge toSameEdgesOfView:self.view];


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(insertNewObject:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
    self.detailViewController = (DetailViewController *)[[self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject] topViewController];
}
```

The above code  is how I have setup the UIView within the ViewController. It is expected to be of size 20x45. The code for dragging is below:

```
-(void)dragging:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    if(gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
        {
            //NSLog(@"Received a pan gesture");
        self.panCoord = [gesture locationInView:gesture.view];
        [self.tableView setScrollEnabled:NO];

        }
    CGPoint newCoord = [gesture locationInView:gesture.view];
    float dX = newCoord.x-self.panCoord.x;
    float dY = newCoord.y-self.panCoord.y;
    CGFloat newXPoint;
    CGFloat newYPoint;

    gesture.view.frame = CGRectMake(gesture.view.frame.origin.x+dX, gesture.view.frame.origin.y+dY, gesture.view.frame.size.width, gesture.view.frame.size.height);
    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        newYPoint = gesture.view.frame.origin.y+dY;
        if (gesture.view.frame.origin.x+dX<(self.view.frame.size.width/2)) {
            newXPoint = 0;
        }
        else {
            newXPoint = self.view.frame.size.width - gesture.view.frame.size.width;
//The below is just an attempt to remove and re-add constraints so the view will stick to the right side of the screen. It is not working :( 
            [self.view removeConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.anotherView
                                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationLessThanOrEqual
                                                                     toItem:self.view
                                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                                 multiplier:1.0
                                                                   constant:0]];

            [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.anotherView
                                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationLessThanOrEqual
                                                                     toItem:self.view
                                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                                 multiplier:1.0
                                                                   constant:0]];


        }


            //        self.draggedViewCoordinate = gesture.view.frame.origin;

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.70];
        [UIView setAnimationDelay:0.0];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
        [self.anotherView layoutIfNeeded];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        [self.tableView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    }

}
```

I am not getting how to update the constraints so the view will stick to the new dragged location. Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The accepted answer is incorrect. It's very expensive operation for UI to add/remove constraints.
Proper solution would be changing

```
self.yCoordinate.constant
```

and

```
self.xCoordinate.constant
```

properties based on dX and dY.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I solved it with the below code!

```
-(void)dragging:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    if(gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
        {
            //NSLog(@"Received a pan gesture");
        self.panCoord = [gesture locationInView:gesture.view];
        [self.tableView setScrollEnabled:NO];

        }
    CGPoint newCoord = [gesture locationInView:gesture.view];
    float dX = newCoord.x-self.panCoord.x;
    float dY = newCoord.y-self.panCoord.y;
    CGFloat newXPoint;
    CGFloat newYPoint;
    gesture.view.frame = CGRectMake(gesture.view.frame.origin.x+dX, gesture.view.frame.origin.y+dY, gesture.view.frame.size.width, gesture.view.frame.size.height);
    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        newYPoint = gesture.view.frame.origin.y+dY;
        CGFloat newYPosition = (self.view.frame.size.height/2) - newYPoint - 20;
        if (gesture.view.frame.origin.x+dX<(self.view.frame.size.width/2)) {
            [self.view removeConstraint:self.xCoordinate];
            [self.view removeConstraint:self.yCoordinate];

            self.xCoordinate = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.anotherView
                                                            attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                            relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationLessThanOrEqual
                                                               toItem:self.view
                                                            attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                           multiplier:1.0
                                                             constant:0];

            [self.view addConstraint:self.xCoordinate];

            self.anotherView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

            self.yCoordinate = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.anotherView
                                                            attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                            relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                               toItem:self.view
                                                            attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                           multiplier:1.0
                                                             constant:-newYPosition];
            [self.view addConstraint:self.yCoordinate];

        }
        else {
            newXPoint = self.view.frame.size.width - gesture.view.frame.size.width;


            [self.view removeConstraint:self.xCoordinate];
            [self.view removeConstraint:self.yCoordinate];

            self.xCoordinate = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.anotherView
                                                            attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                            relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationLessThanOrEqual
                                                               toItem:self.view
                                                            attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                           multiplier:1.0
                                                             constant:0];

            [self.view addConstraint:self.xCoordinate];

            self.anotherView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

            self.yCoordinate = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.anotherView
                                                            attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                            relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                               toItem:self.view
                                                            attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                           multiplier:1.0
                                                             constant:-newYPosition];
            [self.view addConstraint:self.yCoordinate];



        }


            //        self.draggedViewCoordinate = gesture.view.frame.origin;

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.70];
        [UIView setAnimationDelay:0.0];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
        [self.anotherView layoutIfNeeded];
                //        gesture.view.frame = CGRectMake(newXPoint, newYPoint, gesture.view.frame.size.width, gesture.view.frame.size.height);
        [UIView commitAnimations];

        [self.tableView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    }

}
```

Essentially, I maintained a reference to the constraints. This helped me in removing/re-adding the constraints based on  the position of the dragged view.

Comment: I believe you can just change the constant property of the constraint and then call layoutIfNeeded

Answer (score 1):

This simplified version solved for me when dragging down and up:

```
@implementation SomeController
{
    float beginDragPointY;
    NSLayoutConstraint someConstraint;
}
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    // Define someConstraint 
}

- (void) onDragGesture: (id) sender
{
    UIPanGestureRecognizer* recognizer = (UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender;
    UIGestureRecognizerState state = recognizer.state;
    CGPoint translation = [sender translationInView:self.view];

    switch(state)
    {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
            NSLog(@"Translation began %f %f", translation.x, translation.y);
            beginDragPointY = translation.y;
        break;

        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:
            showBasicEventAnnotationConstraint.constant += translation.y - beginDragPointY;
            beginDragPointY = translation.y;
            [self.view setNeedsLayout];
        break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled:
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed:
        case UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible:
        default:
            break;
    }

    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}
```